# Port 32-Bit Windows driver to 64-Bit Windows

Tags: c, windows-7, 64-bit, driver, wdk

Since our applications run in fullscreen mode, we have developed a keyboard hooking driver to disable user input for keys like `ALT+F4`, `CTRL+ALT+DEL` and so forth.

The driver is developed in C using the Windows Driver Kit.

Compiling for 32-Bit works and it loads the driver on Windos 7 32-Bit and it works as expected.

Compiling for 64-Bit works and it just doesn't load the driver on Windows 7 64-bit (but is signed and listed in the keyboard drivers).

Following are our `SetEnv` settings:

```
setenv c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1 fre x64
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Do I need to make specific changes to the code to make it work on 64-Bit?

Comment: Nothing to go on.  Try this: http://www.chris123nt.com/2007/04/28/driver-signing-in-x64/

Comment: Thank you for this link. We've already tried this without success...

Comment: What are the errors that are generated? How do you  load a driver, which didn't compile? Be a bit more specific please ... (NB: a 32-bit driver won't load on x64)

Comment: There are no errors generated. Compiling works and the drivers are loaded through a custom script which puts them into the system32/drivers directory and adds the necessary keys to the registry. It's built upon the Sysinternals Ctrl2Cap.

Answer (score 3):

The build option looks correct.  You wouldn't need to make changes to the code unless the code makes assumptions about things like the size of pointers, integers etc.  Scripts that "install" drivers by mucking with the registry etc. may not work.

Drivers in Win7 64 bit need to be either WHQL test signed by Microsoft, test signed by yourself, or signed with a trusted certificate.

The first just installs.  The second requires booting with the test signing configuration option.  The third will display a warning when you install asking you whether or not you trust the provider.

Normally during development you'd test sign the driver:
[MSDN instructions on test signing a driver package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547660%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)